# Raspberry Pi Camera -- extract NAL units from Raspivid

Tags: h.264

I'm trying to extract NAL units from raw .h264 files generated by Raspivid. I'm piping the output of Raspivid to netcat as so:

Raspivid  | nc -u IPaddress Port

I can receive and save the stream on a client. The .h264 file that results actually DOES play in VLC.

However, my ultimate goal is to parse the NAL units out of the file and feed them into Media Codec on Android. To do this, I need the SPS and PPS data.

The problem is that I'm not finding the corresponding NAL units when examining the Hex output of the generated file. I'm looking for "00 00 00 01 67" for SPS.

All I'm seeing are a ton of "00 00 00 01 21", 
"00 00 00 01 27", 
"00 00 00 01 28"
etc.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Edit: I AM using the -ih option on Raspivid so it should be inserting those values regularly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys on the Pi forums helped me out. I was basing my 67 number on a blog post describing NAL units, but I didn't consider that the hex could change regardless of the last five bits still being 7. Total noob.